# Fantasy book about a boy who is a hybrid of angel (or elf) and human

Tags: story-identification, novel, elves

The book is about a boy who comes to realize that his father is a dark angel/elf who used his mother to get a new elf/angel into the world. When he grew up, he was taken by a certain elf/angel, named Claudia. I remembered they said her wings were dark purple to silver at the top of the feathers (their wings are like angel wings, but I don't know anymore if they were elves or angels).

To gain his wings the boy had to train his powers first, with Claudia, in a cave with crystals, where other elves/angels lived. He had to try to summon his weapon.  After that, he had to do a mentally difficult test to see if he was like his father, a dark elf/angel or a good one, with colored wings.

The book was written in Dutch.

I also remember some part of the cover of the book:
It was a grey wrinkled background with two black wings on it. The title was written in red I believe. Maybe in very sharp letters, I'm not sure about that.

I read it in 2013. But I have no idea if it has been translated in English.

Comment: Could you please add when exactly you read this (how many years ago)? Also, could it have been a book translated from English?

Comment: @Gallifreyan Done ^^

Comment: That's a good amount of detail, hope you find it.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Thank you, and I hope so too.

Comment: It's not a fantasy book...;) http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4468954/Man-spends-25k-plastic-surgery-elf.html

Comment: @TGar, yes it is, I read it, and it certainly wasn't based on a true story.